# CheckBox showing faded in Marshmallow

Tags: android

```
<CheckBox
 android:id="@+id/CheckBox01_district"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:gravity="end"
 android:padding="10dp"
 android:layout_marginRight="6sp"
 android:focusable="false" />
```

I  have  written this  for  checkbox  .Its  showing  well in  Kitkat but  showing  faded in  Marshmallow.

Comment: change your android:layout_marginRight from SP to DP. check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/what-is-the-difference-between-px-dp-dip-and-sp-on-android)

Comment: Its not  right answer

Comment: it is a suggestion not an answer

Answer (score 0):

You should use `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox` instead of CheckBox :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox 
android:id="@+id/CheckBox01_district"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="end"
android:padding="10dp"
android:layout_marginRight="6sp"
android:focusable="false"/>
```

Comment: It  is  still not  showing  .  Faded in  marshmallow